# Delete a file from contentResolver only delete the entry from database (not file)

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I try to delete a file using contentResolver but only delete the entry from database, not the real file. So I try delete first the entry and later the file:

```
int rows = context.getContentResolver().delete(
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=" + idSong, null);

// Remove file from card
if (rows != 0) {
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, idSong);
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
if(!f.delete())
    Log.d("fail-2", "fail-2");  
}
else
Log.d("fail-1", "fail-1");
```

...and the output is "fail-2". Why?

Why ContentResolver doesn't delete the real file? Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
    // Remove entry from database
    int rows = context.getContentResolver().delete(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=" + idSong, null);

    // Remove file from card
    if (rows != 0) {
        try {
            File f = new File(path);
            if (f.delete())
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MusicDB", "file: '" + path
                    + "' couldn't be deleted", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

But why contentResolver doesn't delete the file??

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in 4.2, it zeros the file, but does not delete it.  I was actually hoping it would just remove it from the MediaStore and not delete it from the file system.  Either way, this appears to be an Android bug.

I'm running into an issue when updating a file.  The issue I'm having is that the media scanner is not deleting the old entry on rescan, so you end up with two entries.

Answer (score 0):

try this one in kotlin

```
   contentResolver.delete(
          MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
          ,"_data" + "=?", 
          arrayOf(path) )
```